# Is there a real life equivalent to Bean's Alcoholic Cider in Fantastic Mr. Fox?

Tags: cider

Mr. Fox says the cider "burns in your throat, boils in your stomach, and tastes almost exactly like pure melted gold."

To me, that sounds like an ABV of at least 25-30%, but I've never seen an alcoholic cider on the market anywhere near that.

Something similar Boggis and Bunce's poultry is pretty easy to procure, but Bean's cider is the bottleneck in my plan. I really want to try something like that, but I'm not sure it's even possible to produce.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there are several drinks that match that description.

[Apple Jack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Applejack_(drink)) comes to mind. It's made by freeze distillation of apple cider. It's about 25-40% ABV. It's nasty stuff if you've ever had some.

In Germany, there is drink that I used to drink when I lived there called [ApfelKorn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apfelkorn). This is just spirits with apple flavor added. This is about 20% ABV. It's actually considered Apple Schnapps.

There are two types of [Apple Brandy](http://www.ejbrandy.com/eandj-brandy-apple). Cider distilled into clear spirits and aged like Whisky and Brandy (grapes) infused with apple liqueur.

Then of course there is [apple liqueur](https://www.berentzenusa.com/products/apple-liqueur/)

My guess is that it's Apple Jack. If you want to make apple jack, it's pretty simple. Just take some hard cider and freeze it in your freezer and pour out the stronger liquid. [Here are some instructions](http://www.distillingliquor.com/2015/02/13/how-to-make-applejack-freeze-distillation/)